# Optimize tests in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, optimization

In this simple test, after being sure that the index is valid, does it worth to assign a variable instead of calling two times objectAtIndex: method ?

```
NSString *s = [myArray objectAtIndex:2];
if (s) {
Test *t = [Test initFromString:s];
}
```

instead of

```
if ([myArray objectAtIndex:2]) {
Test *t = [Test initFromString:[myArray objectAtIndex:2]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the performance point of view it’s not worth it, unless the code lies on a really hot path (and you would know that). Sending a message is [practically free](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations-leopard-edition.html) and looking up an object on a given index is also too fast to care in most situations.

The change makes the code more readable, though: First, you can name the thing that you pull from the container (like `testName`). Second, when reading the two repeated calls to `objectAtIndex` you have to make sure that it’s really the same code. After you introduce the separate variable it’s obvious, there’s less cognitive load.